# Cannot run the Spring Boot application: o.s.boot.SpringApplication application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I cannot start the Spring Boot application.

Below are the stack-traces and the content of pom file:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

----------

org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:746) [spring-boot-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:406) [spring-boot-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1259) [spring-boot-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT]at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.4.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at com.techm.jobs.user.JobZillaApplication.main(JobZillaApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [springfox.documentation.spring.web.ObjectMapperConfigurer] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@659e0bfd]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:418) ~[spring-orm-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389) ~[spring-orm-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:336) ~[spring-orm-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1100) ~[spring-beans-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            ... 16 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
            at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:5.3.0-SNAPSHOT]
            ... 22 common frames omitted
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
            ... 26 common frames omitted
```

**pom.xml** file:

```xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
            
            
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
            <groupId>com.techm.jobs.user</groupId>
            <artifactId>JobZilla</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <name>JobZilla</name>
            <description>JobZilla project for Spring Boot</description>
        
            <properties>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            </properties>
        
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
           <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
           <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
                
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
                <artifactId>byte-buddy-agent</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.16</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            </dependencies>
        
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>spring-milestones</id>
                    <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                    <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>spring-milestones</id>
                    <name>Spring Milestones</name>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>spring-snapshots</id>
                    <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
                    <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        
        </project>
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper` Check if you have `com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper` class in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The library springfox-swagger2 expects you to provide the jackson-databind dependency yourself, see https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/2.7.0/gradle/dependencies.gradle line 60-61.

Simply add a dependency to jackson-databind:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
```

2.8.7 is taken from the springfox-swagger2 dependencies.gradle as well.